# Why does Wireshark show Version TLS 1.2 here instead of TLS 1.3?

Tags: wireshark

I'm accessing TLS 1.3 test server "https://tls13.pinterjann.is" via a java http client using TLS 1.3. Everything seems to work fine as the html response indicates:

[image: HTML Response]

What I don't understand: Why does Wireshark show in the overview Protocol TLSv1.3 but in the details Version TLS 1.2?

Is Wireshark just displaying the wrong Version or am I actually using TLS 1.2?

Thanks in advance for your support.

[image: Wireshark ClientHello]
[image: Wireshark HelloRetry]
[image: Wireshark ClientHello 2]
[image: Wireshark ServerHello]

Comment: Is your copy of Wireshark up to date?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Wireshark version 2.6.5.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it said 1.3 on one line  but then said 1.0 on another, then 1.2 on yet another.  Have you tried a different capture utility, such as Fiddler?

Comment: No I didn't try another capture tool. Does Fiddler support displaying TLS 1.3 messages?

Comment: BTW: I found this capture https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/64d433b1585a on the internet, where the same thing happens. I guess it's an inaccurracy in the way Wireshark displays the version in the detail section.

Comment: As far as I know, Fiddler does.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 19):

Sorry, for the confusion, I was missing the exact TLS 1.3 semantics: For instance, in the Client Hello, the field "version" must contain the fixed value 0x0303 (TLS 1.2), while the prefered version is contained in the extension "supported versions".

From RFC 8446 (TLS 1.3 spec):

```
struct {
      ProtocolVersion legacy_version = 0x0303;    /* TLS v1.2 */
      Random random;
      opaque legacy_session_id<0..32>;
      CipherSuite cipher_suites<2..2^16-2>;
      opaque legacy_compression_methods<1..2^8-1>;
      Extension extensions<8..2^16-1>;
  } ClientHello;
```

> legacy_version:  In previous versions of TLS, this field was used for
>         version negotiation and represented the highest version number
>         supported by the client.  Experience has shown that many servers
>         do not properly implement version negotiation, leading to "version
>         intolerance" in which the server rejects an otherwise acceptable
>         ClientHello with a version number higher than it supports.  In
>         TLS 1.3, the client indicates its version preferences in the
>         "supported_versions" extension (Section 4.2.1) and the
>         legacy_version field MUST be set to 0x0303, which is the version
>         number for TLS 1.2.  TLS 1.3 ClientHellos are identified as having
>         a legacy_version of 0x0303 and a supported_versions extension
>         present with 0x0304 as the highest version indicated therein.
>         (See Appendix D for details about backward compatibility.)

This agrees with what Wireshark displays:

[image: Wireshark supported versions]

Comment: Nice find.  Congrats.

Comment: This was covered 4 days ago in a lecture at 35C3: https://media.ccc.de/v/35c3-9607-the_rocky_road_to_tls_1_3_and_better_internet_encryption The "version intolerance" problem seems to be quite widespread on "enterprise" devices

Answer (score 6):

> Why does Wireshark show in the overview Protocol TLSv1.3 but in the details Version TLS 1.2?

Wireshark reports TLS 1.3 in the protocol column due to Server Hello containing a [Supported Versions extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.2.1) with TLS 1.3.

Recall that TLS sessions begin with a handshake to negotiate parameters such as the protocol version and ciphers. The client sends a Client Hello handshake message in a TLS record containing:

- TLS Record - Version: minimum supported TLS version (in TLS 1.2 and before). In TLS 1.3, this field is not really used and MUST be 0x0303 ("TLS 1.2") or 0x301 ("TLS 1.0") for compatibility purposes. Reference: [RFC 8446 (page 79)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#page-79)
- Client Hello - Version: maximum supported TLS version (in TLS 1.2 and before). In TLS 1.3, this field is not used but MUST be set to 0x0303 ("TLS 1.2"). Reference: [RFC 8446 (4.1.2. Client Hello)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.1.2)
- Client Hello - Supported Versions Extension: list of supported versions. This is the only value used by TLS 1.3 implementations (which may agree TLS 1.3, 1.2 or other versions). Reference: [RFC 8446 (4.2.1. Supported Versions)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.2.1)

The server sends a Server Hello handshake message with:

- Server Hello - Version: negotiated version (for TLS 1.2 and before). If TLS 1.3 is negotiated, it MUST be set to 0x0303 ("TLS 1.2").
- Server Hello - Supported Versions: a single negotiated version (for TLS 1.3). Cannot be used to negotiate earlier versions.

So in TLS 1.2, the client sends a range of supported versions while a TLS 1.3 client sends a list of supported versions. The server will then pick a single version, but for compatibility purposes it will use a new field for selecting TLS 1.3 or newer.

(Even if a client advertises support for some version (e.g. via a TLS record version containing "TLS 1.0"), it could still fail the handshake though if the server agrees to this low version.)

Another thing to be aware of: Wireshark tries to interpret a packet immediately as it is received. At the time the Client Hello is received, it will not know the final version and therefore assume the TLS Record Version. When the Server Hello is received, it can adjust the version accordingly:

```
$ tshark -r test/captures/tls13-rfc8446.pcap 
    1   0.000000     10.9.0.1 → 10.9.0.2     TLSv1 304 Client Hello
    2   0.002634     10.9.0.2 → 10.9.0.1     TLSv1.3 658 Server Hello, Change Cipher Spec, Application Data
    3   0.005266     10.9.0.1 → 10.9.0.2     TLSv1.3 130 Change Cipher Spec, Application Data
    4   0.005772     10.9.0.2 → 10.9.0.1     TLSv1.3 468 Application Data
...
```

In a two-pass dissection (which also includes the Wireshark GUI), the agreed version will be known when it prints the results of the second pass:

```
$ tshark -r test/captures/tls13-rfc8446.pcap -2
    1   0.000000     10.9.0.1 → 10.9.0.2     TLSv1.3 304 Client Hello
    2   0.002634     10.9.0.2 → 10.9.0.1     TLSv1.3 658 Server Hello, Change Cipher Spec, Application Data
    3   0.005266     10.9.0.1 → 10.9.0.2     TLSv1.3 130 Change Cipher Spec, Application Data
    4   0.005772     10.9.0.2 → 10.9.0.1     TLSv1.3 468 Application Data
...
```

Test capture used above: https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/master/test/captures/tls13-rfc8446.pcap